# Java web socket client in docker-container can not connect to websocket java server in another container

Tags: java, docker, networking, hostname

I have a super simple docker-compose file:

```
services:
  app:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
    - myapp-redis
    - myapp-partner
    ports:
    - 1967:1967
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
    - backend

  myapp-partner:
    container_name: myapp-partner
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-Partner
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
    - backend

  myapp-redis:
    container_name: myapp-redis
    restart: always
    image: redis:6.0.5
    networks:
    - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

If i port-forward x:y (aka `ports` config), i can access all services in my host machine's localhost
And also it is possible to `telnet myapp-partner` from `myapp` container console.
But when i simply try to connect web socket (`ws://myapp-partner:8080/quotes`)from the running Java app in `myapp` container i get `connection refused` error.
I have checked the network, all containers are attached themselves succesfully into it and like i said telnet communication is successful via command-lines.

What can be the problem?
(host network-mode works but then `myapp` becomes unreachable on `localhost:1967`)

Comment: What network interface does your code bind to?

Comment: Not sure if i understood the question correctly but it is basically org.java_websocket.WebSocket and all components connects each other succesfully when i throw away docker. @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: Are all ports exposed in the dockerfiles?

Comment: Yes exactly @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. 8080 for myapp-partner and 6379 for redis.

Comment: Show the code that creates the websocket in myapp-partner.